Extracting Values from a JSON Array in Snowflake
We have a table that has PromoCodes as a JSON Array for each Order as following



order_id
promo_json_array




111
[{PromoCode:"bbb", Discount: -1 }, {PromoCode:"aaa", Type:FreeShip}]


222
[{PromoCode:"ccc", Discount: -2}]


333
[{PromoCode:"ccc", Discount: -2}, {PromoCode:"aaa"}, {PromoCode:"eee"} ]


444




For each Order, I need to get the comma-separate list of PromoCodes, if there are any.
I am using a Flatten to achieve this as following:
with orders as (
  select 111 as order_id, '[{PromoCode:"bbb", Discount: -1 }, {PromoCode:"aaa", Type:FreeShip}]' as promo_json_array
  union all
  select 222, '[{PromoCode:"ccc", Discount: -2}]'
  union all
  select 333, '[{PromoCode:"ccc", Discount: -2}, {PromoCode:"aaa"}, {PromoCode:"eee"} ]'
  union all
  select 444, null
)
--select * from orders;
select order_id, listagg (f.value:PromoCode, ', ')
from orders
, lateral flatten(input => parse_json(orders.promo_json_array)::variant, OUTER => TRUE) as f
group by all




order_id
promo_codes_applied




222
ccc


333
ccc, aaa, eee


111
bbb, aaa


444



444




However this is very slow on a large number of Orders, especially if we have lot of elements + key-values in the JSON array. Is there a more optimized way to achieve this?

It's difficult to help with performance questions without knowing the actual volume of data, warehouse size, and the query profile information.  I don't see anything wrong with the query itself, but profile information, spillage information, and warehouse size could provide some insight.  What happens if you use a larger warehouse?

if it is once off, pay the cost, if, you do it ALL THE TIME, pay for the storage of matrializing that table, ether cook the promo_json_array into promo_codes_applied or some other set of data that is more how you use it, so that it Total Cost of Ownership, is lower. This dance of finding the local minima of cost for the perfromance usage, is the mind game to keeps you happy (aka your job).

also your results with the double 444 row feel wrong for a outer=>true setting with a single input. And in general you will get bad results (leaking across row boundaries) if you use the direct source values, and you should instead add a SEQ8() and group on that, which with luck the flattern provides, thus GROUP BY ordr_d, f.seq should be you result.

Hi @MikeWalton. The query is a lot faster on larger WH. However there is no spillage on the small either, so I am guessing the computer power of the large WH is helping.

The fastest way to perform this operation is with the TRANSFORM function in Snowflake. This approach is performed in-place, it doesn't require pivoting and grouping the resultset.
WITH orders AS (...)

SELECT
    order_id,
    TRANSFORM(
       parse_json(orders.promo_json_array)::ARRAY,
       promo OBJECT -> promo:"PromoCode"
    ) as promo_codes_applied
FROM orders
;


